# processing delete key not reading

Tags: java, keyboard, processing

so I am trying to have a delete function in my processing program:

```
void keyPressed(int event){
  for(int i = 0; i < searchbars.length; i++){
    if(event == 127){
      searchbars[i].delete();
    }
    else{
      searchbars[i].write(key);
    }
  }
}
```

the delete key in java is represented by the integer 127. I guess I don't fully understand the `event` option for [processing's keyPressed()](http://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html)

I tried doing the [key](http://processing.org/reference/key.html) method as follows:

```
void keyPressed(){
  for(int i = 0; i < searchbars.length; i++){
    if(key == DELETE){
      searchbars[i].delete();
    }
    else{
      searchbars[i].write(key);
    }
  }
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work either! **What am I doing wrong?**

## note:

`searchbars` is a list of searchbars that are a class/element in the GUI that can have a character written into them with `write()`, and has the last character deleted when `delete()` is called

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Set a breakpoint at the beginning of keyPressed() and check the value of key. If you don't know how to debug, at least write a System.out.println(key); for now so you can see the value. Also, did you mean to loop through ALL the searchbars every time a key is pressed? Currently if it is delete, ALL searchbars are deleted, or otherwise all searchbars are written.

Comment: each searchbar has a boolean value for if it's being used. Only one can be used at a time. `delete()` and `write()` only applies if it is the one being used so the loop is fine.

Comment: but yes that had me figure it out. Delete has a keycode of 8. even though it says that you shouldn't use keycode for Delete and such, it prints out an unreadable symbol otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check the integer with keyCode

```
void keyPressed(){
  for(int i = 0; i < searchbars.length; i++){
    if(keyCode == 8){
      searchbars[i].delete();
    }
    else{
      searchbars[i].write(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your original code works for me. Is it possible you confused Delete with Backspace?

Comment: Perhaps he is referencing the macOSX 'delete' key, which is actually backspace